# Need a preg_replace or best option for this conversion

Tags: php, regex

I'm sure this is simple and I have tried formatting several combinations my example S1, Ep1 = 10001 or S1, Ep2 = 10002 preg_ combinations and all fails, not my forte'

The format i need is as follows:

```
$link = array('Episodes from link');

$str = preg_replace('/^s/+', '0', $link);
echo   $str(array(  
  '10001',
  '10002',
  '10003',
));
```

and so on...

Keep getting to many zeros because of the empty, comma and the characters, any help is greatly appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense to me, please phrase the question differently. I can see that your regex is incorrect for whatever you are trying to match.

Comment: hwnd is spot on the answer to my question is very close to answered and you put it on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear and I may be way off, but here is my attempt to your question.

```
$link = array('S1, Ep1', 'S1, Ep2', 'S1, Ep3', 'S1, Ep10');

$results = preg_replace_callback('~^S(\d+)\D+(\d+)$~m', 
         function($m) {
            $which = strlen($m[2]) > 1 ? '00' : '000';
            return $m[1] . $which . $m[2];
         }, array_values($link));

print_r($results);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10001
    [1] => 10002
    [2] => 10003
    [3] => 10010
)
```

Comment: So close the when it hit's the double digit's it maintains 3 internal zeros but it should drop a zero when hitting double digit's example: S1, Ep1 = 10001 and the double digit example: S1, Ep10 = 10010 but so close, thank you...

Comment: It work's but is to complicated for my query if I rearrange my query I can get it to run but the data name I was using has now changed to array then my data name episodes example: array() then the data name episodes then the open and closed paren() which breaks the data path, can't be modified the way I'm pulling this referenced info, but so close, the first response was almost perfect except the zero issue. thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: Well you will have to run two preg_replace calls then otherwise this is the only way.

Comment: I do have one other option which is much easier, but again I drew a blank. All I wanted to do is write a piece of code to simply create a sequential array of numbers starting at 10000 and running to 10050 but all my research came up using "range" function which intern did the same thing created an array in the array and hosed up the data naming convention. Why don't they gave a simple $num = range('10000');  or something similar that doesn't create the array? Thanks

Comment: Competed this query with a few modifications this was the exact answer to the question I had asked thumbs up to "hwnd" and thank you very much!